# how javascript excutes callback with parameters

Tags: javascript, parameters, reference, callback

i am in trouble with javascript‘s callback,my code seems simple:

```
        var i =0;
        for (; i < listSize+1; i++) {
            var content = "content"+i;
            $("#" + content).focus(function () {
                $("#" + content).keydown(check(new Number(i)));
                $("#" + content).keyup(check(new Number(i)));    
            });
        }
```

where `lisetSize=3` in my test case and `content` is the html element's id

and the callback function `check(my_num)` is:

```
        function check(my_num) {
            var content = "content"+my_num;
        }
```

then i try to trigger this function through keyboard input.

however,i got the result that `content=content4` all the time via my broswer's debugger,even though the listening element is content0

i have try anyway such as `$.extend({},i)` `$.extend(true,{},i)`

it make no difference

now i have no idea about this problem,how can i just pass a value but no reference to the callback function's parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not declaring the handlers correctly.

Replace:

```
$("#" + content).keydown(check(new Number(i)));
$("#" + content).keyup(check(new Number(i)));
```

With:

```
$("#" + content).keydown(function(){check(new Number(i));});
$("#" + content).keyup(function(){check(new Number(i));});
```

What you *need* to pass to `keyup` and `keydown`, are functions that need to be called when keyboard events happen.

What you *were* passing to `keyup` and `keydown`, were the results of calling `check(new Number(i))`.

Also, since you're declaring these in a loop, you'll want to copy the number to a new variable, in order to reference the *current* loop iteration's value:

```
$("#" + content).focus(function () {
    var currentNumber = i;
    $("#" + content).keydown(function(){check(currentNumber);});
    $("#" + content).keyup(function(){check(currentNumber);});   
});
```

Comment: If you are able to rewrite your loop to use `Array.prototype.forEach()` (and you don't need to support older browsers), then you don't have to worry about closing over a loop variable either.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for [Cerbrus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1835379/cerbrus),even though there is still problem.

Now I realize that the problem was caused by misunderstanding the real running order.

Even after the loop ends up, `$("#" + content).focus` will still be called once user click the element.And then,the program starts the code

```
function () {
            $("#" + content).keydown(function(){check(currentNum);});
            $("#" + content).keyup(function(){check(currentNum);});    
        }
```

As the loop has ended,`currentNum=4`,so everything got an error.

Here is my solution:

```
for (var i = 0; i < listSize + 1; i++) {
            var content = "content" + i;
            $("#" + content).focus(function () {
                $(this).keydown(function () {
                    check($(this));
                });
                $(this).keyup(function () {
                    check($(this));
                });
            });
        }

function check(trigger) {
            var my_num = getContentNum(trigger);
        }

function getContentNum(content) {
            return (content.attr("id").charCodeAt(7))-48;
        }
```

Not elegant but useful.